# Spring Boot Apps with Single Port

Tags: spring-boot, server, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

Currently ,I have an infrastructure like this.[image]
Client hit the load balancer and it round robin to my Application Server (JBOSS). So there is few services deployed as war  in server which provide REST endpoints. Since the deployments are war every service is exposed to single port via application server  (Traditional way)

I'm planning to migrate my services out of my application server (too heavy) and convert it to spring boot application (JARs). The plan is to realign the infrastructure like this [image]

So my concern is when I convert to spring boot jar each service is exposed to different ports. I'm not planning to change any port in load balancer to avoid conflict with client .

Is there any way I can route the service to it's on app by identifying its context root ???

(I know an application server can solve this issue . but just want to know other views )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you plan to convert your applications to spring boot, you can also give [Netflix Zuul](https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/) a go.

> Zuul is an edge service that provides dynamic routing, monitoring, resiliency, security, and more.

In your case, you don't have to create filters. You can simply create a configuration for routing the request to your REST endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

You can put NGINX in front of the Spring-Boot apps forwarding each context path to the desired port.

Like you said, the application server can solve this issue, so you just have to replicate this behaviour with another tool like NGINX or Apache HTTP Server.

Comment: Thanks , that sounds logical